# Retriving a value from Array of Vector Value

Tags: json, haskell

I have the following code:

```
case (HashMap.lookup "key123" jsnObj) of
  Just c -> 
    case c of
      Array d -> print d
```

and the result:

```
fromList [String "123.00000",String "0.456789"]
```

I can't figure out how I can retrieve the second value from it. Your suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `Data.Vector` imported and then you can simply use the indexing function `!` on the `Vector` `d`:

```
case HashMap.lookup "key123" jsnObj of
    Just c -> case c of
        Array d -> print $ d ! 1
```

Comment: this works. I wonder, is there another way (at a lower level, perhaps) to do it, maybe through pattern matching?

Comment: As far as I know, the vector type does not export it's constructors, so you would not be able to pattern match on it.